# What are the duties of wealthy aside from zakat?

Tags: zakat, money

I read a hadith which says that there are other duties on a wealthy person other than zakat, well I am wondering what those duties might be.

[The Hadith](http://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/3/43):

> Fatimah bint Qais narrated that : she asked -or, the Prophet was asked
>   - about Zakat, and he said: "Indeed there is a duty on wealthy aside from Zakat." Then he recited this Ayah which is in Al-Baqarah: 'It is
>   not Al-Birr (piety, righteousness) that you turn your faces.'
>   (Al-Baqarah 2:177) (Da'if)
>
> حَدَّثَنَا مُحَمَّدُ بْنُ أَحْمَدَ بْنِ مَدُّويَهْ، حَدَّثَنَا
>   الأَسْوَدُ بْنُ عَامِرٍ، عَنْ شَرِيكٍ، عَنْ أَبِي حَمْزَةَ، عَنِ
>   الشَّعْبِيِّ، عَنْ فَاطِمَةَ بِنْتِ قَيْسٍ، قَالَتْ سَأَلْتُ أَوْ
>   سُئِلَ النَّبِيُّ صلى الله عليه وسلم عَنِ الزَّكَاةِ فَقَالَ ‏"‏ إِنَّ
>   فِي الْمَالِ لَحَقًّا سِوَى الزَّكَاةِ ‏"‏ ‏.‏ ثُمَّ تَلاَ هَذِهِ
>   الآيَةَ الَّتِي فِي الْبَقَرَةِ ‏(‏ لَيْسَ الْبِرَّ أَنْ تُوَلُّوا
>   وُجُوهَكُمْ ‏)‏ الآيَةَ ‏.‏

And there is another one I do not remember where it is, but both are weak hadiths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Shia View**

A Muslim should also pay Khums. both Shia and Sunni scholars accept Khums but conflict is about the items that their Khums should be paid.  According to 
"[Khums (The Islamic Tax)](http://www.al-islam.org/beliefs/practices/khums.html#1)":

> "Khums" literally means "one-fifth or 20%". In Islamic legal terminology, it means "one-fifth of certain items which a person acquires as wealth, and which must be paid as an Islamic tax". The Qur'an mentions it in the following verse:
>
> > Know that whatever of a thing you acquire, a fifth of it is for Allah,
> >     for the Messenger, for the near relative, and the orphans, the needy,
> >     and the wayfarer...([8:41](http://tanzil.net/#8:41))
>
> In this verse, the word "ghanimtum" has been used which has been translated as "you acquire". As explained above, it means "certain items which a person acquires as wealth." What are these certain items? According to the ahadith of the Imams of Ahlu 'l-bayt, the items which are eligible for khums are seven:
>
> 1. the profit or the surplus of the income.
> 2. the legitimate wealth which is mixed with some illegitimate wealth.
> 3. mines and minerals.
> 4. the precious stones obtained from sea by diving.
> 5. treasures.
> 6. the land which a dhimmi kafir buys from a Muslim.
> 7. the spoils of war.
>
> However, there are some people who interpret the word "ghanimtum" as "whatever of a thing you acquire as spoils of war," thus confining the obligation of khums to the spoils of war only. This interpretation is based on ignorance of the Arabic language, the history of khums, the Islamic laws and of the interpretation of the Qur'an. To make this point crystal clear, I would like to quote the following arguments from my father, `Allamah Sayyid Saeed Akhtar Rizvi. In reading the following paragraphs, remember that the word ghanimtum has been derived from al-ghanimah.
>
> "The Meaning of Ghanimtum: The famous Arabic dictionary of al-Munjid (by Father Louis Ma'luf of Beirut) says, al-ghanim and al-ghanimah means: (a) What is taken from the fighting enemies by force. (b) All earnings generally...Furthermore, the saying al-ghunm bi 'l-ghurm means that the profit stands against expenses, i.e., as the owner is the sole proprietor of the profit and nobody shares it with him, therefore only he bears all the expenses and risk.'(See the entry under G-N-M; in the 28th edition of al-Munjid (Beirut: Dar el-Machreq, 1986) it is on p. 561. Also see other famous dictionaries like Lisan al-`Arab and al-Qamus.) This implies that in Arabic language al-ghanimah has two meanings: one the spoils of war, and the other 'profit'. The above quoted proverb also proves that 'profit' is not uncommon meaning. When a word in the Qur'an can be interpreted in more than one way, it is incumbent upon the Muslims to seek guidance from the Prophet and the Ahlu 'l-bayt. Otherwise, they would be guilty of tafsir bi 'r-ra'iy (interpreting the Qur'an according to one's own personal views); and this is a sin which pushes the sinner into jahannam.

**Reference and further study:**

- http://www.al-islam.org/laws/khums.html
- http://www.al-islam.org/encyclopedia/chapter6b/4.html
- http://www.islamic-laws.com/khums.htm

Answer (score 1):

The [hadith](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/7/43) even if it was qualified as da'if on sunnah.com has been quoted (at least partly) in several other hadith compilation such as a second narration in [Jami' at-Tirmidhi](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/7/44), in [Sunan ibn Majah](https://sunnah.com/ibnmajah/8/7), in al-Bayhaqi's as-Sunan al-Kubra ([here](https://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?flag=1&bk_no=71&bookhad=7073) in Arabic, where he points that the issue is Hamza ibn Maymoun who has been qualified as da'if by Ahmad ibn Hanbal and ibn Ma'yn and later scholars), in at-Tabarani's al-Mo'jam al-Kabir (see [here](https://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?flag=1&bk_no=84&bookhad=20572) in Arabic), in ad-Darimi's Sunan (see [here](https://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?flag=1&bk_no=8&bookhad=1637) in Arabic) and in those of ad-Daraqotni (see [here](https://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?flag=1&bk_no=76&bookhad=1980) in Arabic) all of these narrated it via more or less the same chain. Better narrations or partial narrations of this hadith appear in the Mosnaf's of ibn abi Shaybah ([here](https://library.islamweb.net/hadith/display_hbook.php?bk_no=96&pid=49973&hid=9974) in Arabic) and 'Abdurrazaq and in abu 'Obayd's an-Nasikh.
(Sources [this thread](https://www.ahlalhdeeth.com/vb/showthread.php?t=230085) and [this article](https://www.alukah.net/sharia/0/84394/) both in Arabic)

The verse our prophet () quoted in some of these narrations is:

> Righteousness is not that you turn your faces toward the east or the west, but [true] righteousness is [in] one who believes in Allah , the Last Day, the angels, the Book, and the prophets and **gives wealth, in spite of love for it, to relatives, orphans, the needy, the traveler, those who ask [for help], and for freeing slaves; [and who] establishes prayer and gives zakah**; [those who] fulfill their promise when they promise; and [those who] are patient in poverty and hardship and during battle. Those are the ones who have been true, and it is those who are the righteous. ([2:177](https://legacy.quran.com/2/177))

This quote includes more than zakah: It includes giving from ones wealth in spite of loving what one is giving, it also make clear that if one is able to one should use the wealth which is aside zakah for needy people and for doing good deeds.
Al-Mubarakpuri in his Tohfat al-Ahwadhi تحفة الأحوذي (see [here](https://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?idfrom=1173&idto=1176&bk_no=56&ID=473) in Arabic) considers these kinds of "gifts" that are mentioned in the verse above as obligatory for a wealthy person.
This is mentioned elsewhere in the qur'an:

> And those within whose wealth is a known right ([70:24](https://legacy.quran.com/70/24))

and goes ahead with ahadith such as:

- > I reached him (the Prophet (ﷺ) ) while in the shade of the Ka`ba; he was saying, "**They are the losers**, by the Lord of the Ka'ba! They are the losers, by the Lord of the Ka'ba!" I said (to myself ), "What is wrong with me? Is anything improper detected in me? What is wrong with me? Then I sat beside him and he kept on saying his statement. I could not remain quiet, and Allah knows in what sorrowful state I was at that time. So I said, ' Who are they (the losers)? Let My father and mother be sacrificed for you, O Allah's Messenger (ﷺ)!" He said, **"They are the wealthy people, except the one who does like this and like this and like this (i.e., spends of his wealth in Allah's Cause**).
  > ([Sahih al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/83/17) and elsewhere like in [Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/12/37))
- > Ibn 'Abbas told Ibn az-Zubayr, "I heard the Prophet, may Allah bless him and grant him peace, say, 'A man is not a believer who fills his stomach while his neighbour is hungry.'" (In al-Bukhari's [al-Adab al-Mufrad](https://sunnah.com/adab:112) and also compiled by at-Tabarani)

So a good wealthy Muslim should consider sharing from his wealth. He shouldn't say deny those who ask him (for food, beverage, help, money etc.) if he is able to give it. Zakat is only the due part which helps us overcome our natural born meanness some scholars say.